# How to add new column with min and max function in Pyspark and group by the data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

PySpark Dataframe: adobeDF

[image]

**Adding new columns to the dataframe:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
adobeDF_new = adobeDF.withColumn('start_date', f.col('Date')).withColumn('end_date', f.col('Date'))
```

Result:

[image]

I am trying to figure out the code on how to save min(Date) values in start_date and max(Date) values in end_Date and grouping the final dataframe by post_evar10 and Type.

What I have tried:The below code works but want to see if there is a better way to do it and limit the data to 60 days from start_date

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
adobe_window = Window.partitionBy('post_evar10','Type').orderBy('Date')
adobeDF_new = adobeDF.withColumn('start_date', min(f.col('Date')).over(adobe_window)).withColumn('end_date', max(f.col('Date')).over(adobe_window))
```

Comment: you can filter the data to limit to 60 days like this: 

`df.filter(F.col('start_date') >= F.date_sub(F.col('start_date'), 60))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following?

```
adobeDF.groupBy("post_evar10").agg(
    f.min("start_date").alias("min_start"),
    f.max("end_date").alias("max_end")
)
```